# Disappearing Messages conversations

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, messages, sms

My mother has a problem since this morning on her iPhone. All her recent conversations since 19 May 2023 on Messages disappeared, except one. The only one that did not disappear is from someone that has a different mobile provider.

The strange thing is that the recent conversations disappeared since 19th May. I know there is a function that can automatically delete a Messages conversation if they are more than a few months or a year old, but this is not the case here. She also doesn't have this function enabled anyway

She also does not use iCloud, so it does not seem to be an issue with that. While I googled about it, I came across some people with similar issue due to iCloud, but my mother does not use it at all.

She turned off and on her iPhone several times, but it did not solve the issue.

Do you know what the issue could be ?

Comment: How old is the most recent backup?  It it probably easiest to retrieve them from there if they are important.

Comment: @MarcWilson The last time she did a backup is in 2018 so unfortunately it's not an option. But thanks for your help. Today, she went to a shop of her mobile provider but they also did not know what it could be